# Convert to lambda expression

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to convert it to Java 8 stream/filter expression.

```
List<IChangelistSummary> bugChanges ........ 
for (IChangelistSummary bugChange : bugChanges)
{
    IChangelist changeInfo = server.getChangelist(bugChange.getId());
    List<IFileSpec> fileSpecs = changeInfo.getFiles(true);
    boolean canAccept = false;
    for (IFileSpec fileSpec : fileSpecs)
    {
        if (fileSpec.getDepotPathString().contains("release1234"))
        {
            canAccept = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (canAccept)
    {
        System.out.println("bugChange="+ bugChange.getId() + "=="+ bugChange.getDescription());
    }
}
```

I already used Java 8 stream/filter to get an instance of 'bugChanges', but I can't figure out how to convert the following code to Java 8.

Comment: Your loop code is unnecessarily complicated: `for(IChangelistSummary bugChange: bugChanges) for(IFileSpec fileSpec: server.getChangelist(bugChange.getId()).getFiles(true)) if(fileSpec.getDepotPathString().contains("release1234")) { System.out.println("bugChange=" + bugChange.getId() + "==" + bugChange.getDescription()); break; }`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 `for-loops` and 2 `if` conditions. It might be replaced with outer and inner stream.

```
 Option<IChangelistSummary> summary = bugChanges.stream()
            .filter(bugChange -> server
                                    .getChangelist(bugChange.getId())
                                    .getFiles(true)
                                    .stream()
                                    .anyMatch( spec ->
                                            spec.getDepotPathString()
                                                .contains("release1234")
                                    )
            )
            .forEach(bug -> 
              System.out.println( 
                "bugChange="+ bug.getId() + "=="+ bug.getDescription())
              )
             );
```

This looks a bit ugly. In the outer stream we examine `bugChange` elements and leaving only elements which satisfy filter `Predicate`. Now in the inner stream we verify if the files associated to the current `bug id` contain  `"release1234"` string. And finally we print the results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the initial value up until the end using a `flatMap`.

```
bugChanges.stream().flatMap(bugChange -> Stream.of(server.getChangelist(bugChange.getId()))
        .map(changeInfo -> changeInfo.getFiles(true))
        .filter(fsList -> fsList.stream().anyMatch(fs -> fs.getDepotPathString().contains("release1234")))
        .map(fs -> bugChange)).forEach(bugChange -> System.out.println("bugChange="+ bugChange.getId() + "=="+ bugChange.getDescription()));
```

Comment: You still can obtain `bugChange` if you will avoid mapping the stream pipeline.

Comment: But to me mapping seems natural. Nothing wrong with that. I guess this usecase does not match with what stream is meant to address.

Comment: Thanks for figuring out my mistake. I have changed my answer as per your suggestion. I really Appreciate it !